# Hibernating EC2 spot instances. When is it possible, when is it not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spot-instances

I'm confused about when you can or cannot hibernate spot instances.

(1.) Under "Hibernation prerequisites," the documentation says that hibernation "is available for On-Demand Instances and Reserved Instances. It is not available for Spot Instances. For more information, see Hibernating interrupted Spot Instances." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html#hibernating-prerequisites

(2.) But the following article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#hibernate-spot-instances

... says that you can set instances to automatically hibernate upon interruption.

---

What explains this apparent contradiction?

My guess would be that you cannot manually initiate hibernation from a spot instance, but you can configure a spot to hibernate automatically upon interruption. Is that right?

Comment: I think you are correct, that you cannot manually hibernate a Spot Instance but it can be hibernated if the Spot Instance is interrupted.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is right. To add on his reply, only the following spot instances can be hibernated upon interruption: C3, C4, C5, M4, M5, R3, and R4, with less than 100 GB of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *manually* hibernate a Spot Instance.

However, a Spot Instance can be hibernated *automatically* if the Spot Instance is interrupted and hibernation has been configured.

See: [Preparing for instance hibernation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#prepare-for-instance-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is supported, but with some exceptions. I suspect this sentence is missing the word *all*:

> It is not available for *all* Spot Instances.

The page that is linked to in the next sentence, [Hibernating interrupted Spot Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html#hibernate-spot-instances), describes the requirements imposed on spot instances.

Answer (score 0):

AWS just announced their [new generation of Hibernation for Spot instance](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/10/ec2-hibernate-additional-instance-families-ec2-spot/?nc1=h_ls).

Now it supports much more AMIs and instance families and you can manually hibernate the Spot instance now (Basically Spot and On-demand instances now have the same hibernation feature). You can start from: [Hibernate your On-Demand Instance or Spot Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html)

Comment: 1) the question itself is off-topic and should be closed, and 2) link-only answers are not valid answers - at best, this should be a comment under the question.